# Python - Looping through list and adding an OR option

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dataframe, for-loop

I have 2 lists in Python.
I want to check whether a keyword appears in my text, if it does then I extract the sentence and if not I put 'not found'. I have another list which are all the columns for all the keywords.

My understanding is the dataframe length and list length to feed into the df need to be the same.

I would like to check if the text has the word 'parrot' OR 'parrots' and if so, then add to the dataframe under the same column.

I would not like an extra column because parrot and parrots are very similar - so they can be placed under the same column.

I am unsure of how I can do this - do I add in a dictionary or a nested list. Please could someone advise?

Dummy code below

```
df_cols=[column1, column2, column3, column4]

#here I have added parrot OR parrots to explain the example

keywords =['cat','dog','parrot', 'parrots','sheep']

text ='the cat was here today. my data is very long. dog is so cute. parrots are so colorful.'

code:
lst=[]
for i in text.split('.')):
    if j in i:
       lst.append('.'.join(text.split('.')) 
    if j == 'parrot' or j == 'parrots':

    #getting and error here - I want to check if parrot/parrots is in my text and 
    #then join it to append one element to my output list

       lst.append(' '.join(i.split('.')[0]))
    else:
       lst.append('not found')
    break
```

desired output:

```
lst = [the cat was here today,dog is so cute, parrots are so colorful, not found]
```

desired dataframe:

```
column1     the cat was here today 
column2     dog is so cute
column3     parrots are so colorful
column4     not found
```

Thank you

Comment: a few questions: Why are you using a dataframe? Why not just use `['cat', 'dog', 'parrot', 'parrots', 'sheep']` to include `parrot` and `parrots`? Why is there a `break` at the end of the `for` loop?

Comment: I add `break` because I want to only find the first instance where the keyword is found in my text. I use a dataframe as I need to output this information into excel for further analysis. So essentially, it loops through each keyword and puts the output into a list which I then put as a dataframe - hope this makes sense? If I include `parrot` and `parrots` then it appends into the list as 2 different items - I need it to append as one item so I can assign the output under one column

Comment: so what is the full structure of the dataframe/table? How do you know what column1, 2, 3, 4 pertain to?

Comment: Column1 is the first item in the for loop - so this would be `the cat was here today` and continue until all the columns are complete.

Comment: you are asking somewhat unusual questions which suggests there may be a better way to achieve what you are trying to do.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have a PDF file and want to iterate through the lines to extract the first sentence where a keyword appears. There are some keywords I have, which have a plural (for instance, parrot and parrots). I would like to check my text to see which one is present and append it to my list. However, I do not want the output as 2 different elements (e,g 'not found' and 'parrots are colorful'). I want the code to be able to identify if we have an output for either one item - then append only that to the list. If neither is found then not found appended is fine. Hope this helps

Comment: that's more helpful, although not completely specified.  What if two keywords are found in a sentence?  Do you really want  the *first* sentence, or all the sentences?  What are you doing with the extracted information/data?

Comment: I'm only looping through the text to find the first sentence where the data is found. With the extracted data I am putting this into a dataframe then output to excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about something like this:

```
>>> keywords ={1:['cat'], 2:['dog'], 3:['parrot', 'parrots'], 4:['sheep']}
>>> def fun(text,split="."):
        for t in text.split(split):
            for c,v in keywords.items():
                if any(k in t for k in v):
                    yield c,t
                    break

>>>
>>> import collections
>>> res = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> for c,t in fun(text):
        res[c].append(t)

    
>>> for c in keywords:
        if c not in res:
            res[c].append("not found")

        
>>> print(res)
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: ['the cat was here today'], 2: [' dog is so cute'], 3: [' parrots are so colorful'], 4: ['not found']})
>>>
```

because we can have multiple keywords for the same column, then make it a dictionary with the keywords per column, then simple search if we find any of them in the text and yield the result founds, I also included the corresponding column those belong, build the result and finally fill in the missing parts

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best code but it does what you ask. Basically it checks if the keyword is `str/set` and do required checks for each case.

```
keywords =['cat','dog',{'parrot', 'parrots'},'sheep']

text ='the cat was here today. my data is very long. dog is so cute. parrots are so colorful.'
text_list = text.split('.')

ls = []
for i in keywords:
    if type(i) is str:
        isFound = False
        for j in text_list:
            if i in j:
                ls.append(j)
                isFound = True
                break

        if isFound == False:
            ls.append('not found')
    elif type(i) is set:
        isFound = False
        for x in i:
            for j in text_list:
                if x in j:
                    ls.append(j)
                    isFound = True
                    break

            if isFound == True:
                break

        if isFound == False:
            ls.append('not found')
```

The result would look like this:

```
['the cat was here today', ' dog is so cute', ' parrots are so colorful', 'not found']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

```py
import re
import pandas as pd

keywords = ['cat','dog', ('parrot', 'parrots'), 'sheep']
sentence_regex = r"[^\.]+\s*(\w*)\s*[^\.]+"  # regex to split sentences
animal_regex = re.compile("^.*\s+({})\s+.*$".format("|".join(w if isinstance(w, str) else "(?:{})".format("|".join(w)) for w in keywords)))

from_animal_to_list = {ww: i for i, w in enumerate(keywords) for ww in (w if isinstance(w, tuple) else [w])}

text = 'the cat was here today. my data is very long. dog is so cute. parrots are so colorful.'
data_for_df = [[] for _ in range(max(from_animal_to_list.values()) + 1)]
for sentence, m in map(lambda s: (s.group(0), animal_regex.match(s.group(0))), re.finditer(sentence_regex, text)):
    animal = m.groups()[0] if m is not None else 'not found'
    if animal != 'not found':
        data_for_df[from_animal_to_list[animal]].append(sentence)
data_for_df = [d if len(d) else ['not found'] for d in data_for_df]

sentence_df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=data_for_df,
    # index=keywords,  # uncomment here if you prefer the name of the animals as index
    index=[f'column{i}' for i, _ in enumerate(data_for_df, start=1)],
    columns=['sentence']
)  # you can transpose this dataframe if you prefer, adding '.T' after ')'

valid_sentences = [d[0] if len(d) else 'not found' for d in data_for_df]
```

`valid_sentences` is `['the cat was here today', ' dog is so cute', ' parrots are so colorful', 'not found']`, while `sentence_df`:

```sh
                         sentence
column1    the cat was here today
column2            dog is so cute
column3   parrots are so colorful
column4                 not found
```